# iperf and Wireshark show different data rate

Tags: wireshark, sniffing, iperf

I was testing the capture performance of a sniffer application in Linux. I have a Windows machine that sends UDP multicast packets to the capture port of the sniffer system using iperf at 8Mbits/s. I use the same port as the iperf server on sniffer system to see how many packets were sent. But when the operation is completed and I open the pcap file and see the summary, the Mbit/s on Wireshark is totally different. iperf says 8.1Mbps and Wireshark says 12Mbits/s. Is this a bug in Wireshark? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Was the sniffer capturing on a Wi-Fi interface?

Comment: Hi.. no the data was captured on wired network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iperf captures the payload data rate, i.e. the actual useful user-data sent inside packets. Wireshark captures all data and overheads, including user-data, plus packet headers around the user data, and frame headers around the packets.